# How to implement a ServerCertificateValidationCallback in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I would like to add a client authentication via X509 certificates so I set my server IIS with **SSL and Client Certificate required**. 
(as said here : [Client Authentication via X509 Certificates in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933477/client-authentication-via-x509-certificates-in-asp-net))

But once the client selects the certificat, the server answers always an HTTP 403.

Therefore in order to customize the validation of the client certificate I added in the global.asax:

```
     protected void Application_Start()
     {
        .......
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

        private static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {            
         //... checking
         return true;
        }
     }
```

But apparently my function is never called and the server response is still *403 permission denied* (certificate judged unsafe).

Do you have any suggestions?