# 404 not found error when trying to initialize Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms, azure-active-directory

I am trying to implement Azure AD on an ASP.NET WebForms application. In the Web.Config, I have added below information:

```
<add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44320/" />
<!--Directory_Name.onmicrosoft.com-->
<add key="ida:Tenant" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/000..." />
<!--App ID URI of service APP-->
<add key="ida:Audience" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/000../federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=00000.." />
<!--Client Application Client ID-->
<add key="ida:TrustedCallerClientId" value="000..." />
```

The Startup.cs file calls Startup.Auth.cs which contains below method.

```
   public void ConfigureAuth_Azure(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                },
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"]
            }); 
    }
```

As soon as it hits this code, it throws error:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException   HResult=0x80131500
> Message=Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not
> Found).   Source=   StackTrace:

Comment: Specifically which line of code throws this error?

Comment: Can you just use the tenant id only ? <add key="ida:Tenant" value="0000-0000-0000-0000-0000..." />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
        // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        RedirectUri = redirectUrl,
        
        // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUrl,
        Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
        ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
        ValidateIssuer = false
        },
        // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
      }});
    }



private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
    context.HandleResponse();
    context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
    return Task.FromResult(0);
     }
```

You can follow the below code sample in Github
(https://github.com/azure-cxp-community/Azure-CXP-Community-Engineering/tree/master/src/DeveloperTools/WebApp.OpenIdConnect.Guide)

And also check with this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/convert-asp-net-webforms-with-windows-authentication-to-use-aad/)

Comment: It is giving error: "Access denied". What permission is required on Azure AD and at which section?

Comment: How does the Authority URL look like?

Comment: @Rkh ,For AD need to have the administrator permission on Azure AD and  URL for authority, composed by Azure Active Directory endpoint and the tenant name (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com)

Comment: Do we need to hardcode the authority URL you mentioned ? As of now authority URL is: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Directory ID}

Comment: You need to mention inside Web.config file  like <add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />

Comment: How it will replace {0} at runtime ?

Comment: Can you please refer this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp . Authentication Handled by OWIN libraries

Comment: I created a sample application using the code mentioned in the above link. I want to know whether I need to add code for X509 certificate validation as well ? I found a link on this: https://www.domstamand.com/loading-x509-cert-from-azure-keyvault-into-netcore-app/ . With the code you suggested, how the handshake will happen without certificate ?

Comment: Can you please explain little bit more about what you actually looking for?

Comment: I want to know if there is a need to add X509 certificate code also as described in the link above? I just created an app with the code given in the link you provided. But it opens a message asking: Justification for access to application

Comment: Message(Justification for access to application)May be  due to some restricted permission  .Can you please check these links https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: Yes I am getting those checked. Just want to know if X509 code also needs to be added or not ?

Comment: X509 certificate used to  authorize the token, Try with adding it.

Comment: Any example on how to authenticate using X509 ?

Comment: Please check with this  document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#special-considerations-for-certificate-validation  and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933477/client-authentication-via-x509-certificates-in-asp-net

Comment: Thanks for providing those links. I have used the code provided by you above. I want to know if it is mandatory to validate using X509 or the code you provided will work ?